# Why is filteredList empty even though I update it in the thread?

Tags: android, multithreading

I am performing a background operation in a background thread in android, like so:

```
switch (position) {   

    final List<Profile> filteredList = new ArrayList<>(0);
    case BELATED:
            Runnable belatedRunnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    for (Profile profile : allBirthdayProfiles) {
                        String birthday = profile.getBirthday();

                        String[] values = birthday.split("-");
                        int day = Integer.parseInt(values[0]);
                        int month = Integer.parseInt(values[1]);

                        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                        String currentDate = formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
                        String[] currentDateValues = currentDate.split("-");
                        int currentDay = Integer.parseInt(currentDateValues[0]);
                        int currentMonth = Integer.parseInt(currentDateValues[1]);

                        if (month < currentMonth)
                            filteredList.add(profile);
                        else if (month == currentMonth && day < currentDay)
                            filteredList.add(profile);
                            Log.d(TAG, filteredList + "   IN THREAD");
                    }
                }
            };
            Thread belatedThread = new Thread(belatedRunnable);
            belatedThread.setName("FilterBelatedThread");
            belatedThread.start();
            break;

        default:
            return allBirthdayProfiles;
    }
    Log.d(TAG, filteredList + "    END RESULT");
    return filteredList;
}
```

The `List<Profile> filteredList` should be modified as the thread runs due to the code appending profiles to the filtered list (`filteredList.add(profile`).

Outside of this switch statement I return the filteredList which in theory should be non null due to an `if` statement being ran (conditions met), however filteredList is empty.

```
D/BirthdayFilter: []    END RESULT
D/BirthdayFilter: [{"birthday":"02-08-2016","favouriteIds":["62InvCZG9jaEmUNiJsssTIjImqY2"],"firstName":"Edal","friendIds":["62InvCZG9jaEmUNiJsssTIjImqY2"],"lastName":"Grunt","userId":"62InvCZG9jaEmUNiJsssTIjImqY2"}]IN THREAD
```

Why is filteredList empty even though I update it in the thread?

Answer (score 4):

This is a classic concurrency issue you are experiencing here. The code inside your `run` method of the `Runnable` is executed parallel to and independently of the main code (which is the whole purpose of `Runnable`s and `Thread`s). As such no order of execution is guaranteed by the Java Runtime! Sometimes your if-statement will be evaluated before the return-statement, most of the time though it will be the other way around.

What you'll probably want to do is notify your main thread of changes made in your `run` method. Depending on your setup this might look similiar to this:

```
Runnable belatedRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // ... normal code here
        updateList(); // notify main thread of changes
    }
}
```

And then add a new method to your activity that updates the list as required:

```
private void updateList() {
    // update your list
}
```

Or if you're using this as an indepenent component, you'll need to pass a listener to the method, so it can notify the caller of the changes. For example, create a new interface:

```
public interface Updateable {
    void update();
}
```

Then implement this interface in your calling class, for example:

```
public MyFragment extends Fragment implements Updateable {
    // ...
    @Override
    public void update() {
        // update your list here
    }
}
```

Then add this to your method:

```
public void filter(/* ... */ final Updateable listener) {
    // inside your run method:
    listener.update();
}
```

Finally call your method inside your calling class, like this:

```
filter(/* ... */ this);
```

You might want to consider passing the list to your `update` interface and method, so you can directly update the list with the new data.

---

Alternatively, if it's a time-consuming background operation, you might want to consider using an `AsyncTask` which has an `onPostExecute` method that makes it easy to use.

Comment: So I should use an interface? @TR4Android

Comment: Since it's an inner class you should be able to call methods of the outer class (e.g. `Activity`) directly. Which class are you using this in?

Comment: I run this from a class called Filter that is called from a fragment like so: new BirthdayFilter(this).filter(mAllProfiles, position)

Comment: I use an interface but for some reason after having added the interface, and overriding the interface method in the fragment, i get this error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.hb.birthpay.fragment.BirthdayFragment

Comment: Yes, have your fragment implement a new `Updateable` interface and then pass that to the filter method. Not sure why that error occurs...